# scala -i option works in v2.9.0 but not in v2.9.2

Tags: scala

v2.9.2 just hangs. Here's the file I'm giving to `-i`:

```
println("I work")
```

And here's the output. First from v2.9.0:

```
$ ~/opt/scala-2.9.0.final/bin/scala -i /tmp/t.scala
Loading /tmp/t.scala...
I work

Welcome to Scala version 2.9.0.final (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.7.0_03).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> :q
$
```

Next, from v2.9.2:

```
$ ~/opt/scala-2.9.2/bin/scala -i /tmp/t.scala
Loading /tmp/t.scala...
^c
$
```

(I have to Ctrl-c it because it just hangs there.)

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: +1 I has the same issue on Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: Try `scala -Yrepl-sync -i ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yep, i have the same problem. Its is a bug:
https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-4945 . Hopefully, it will be solved in 2.10

Comment: according to [https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-5443](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-5443) it is not solved in 2.10

Comment: Thanks, did you see the comment to my question recommending the -Yrepl-sync option? That got it working for me.

Comment: @three-cups yep, I saw it. Your solution is working thanks. I just put info that the problem is already processed into bug ...